# how to extract date from the given filename in java

Tags: java

I have my file names as below

1. C:\Users\name\Documents\repository\zzz\xxx_yyy\new\aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_ZZ_E_20160801_20160831_v1-0.csv
2. C:\Users\name\Documents\repository\zzz\xxx_yyy\new\aaa_bbb_ppp_ccc_ddd_eee_ZZ_E_20160801_20160831_v1-0.csv

I have to write a single java script for both the file format to extract both the dates from each filename.

Can you please help.

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: Hi Sneha, your question is lacking in detail, and smacks of "write code for me". Please check out [ask] and [mcve]. You need to indicate what you've done, as well as a _specific_ issue and expected output. Also might want to clarify if this is java or javascript. I'm voting to close this as it stands currently as too broad since it is lacking in some of those important details (and SO is not a code-writing service).

Comment: You can split the filename by the '_' token and then select the nth and nth+1 tokens if the format is constant

Answer (score 3):

You should use **Regular expressions** to extract dates from filenames like these.

```
private static Date[] extractDatesFromFileName(File file) throws ParseException {
    Date[] dates = new Date[2];

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    String regex = ".*(\\d{8})_(\\d{8}).*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
    if (m.find()) {
        dates[0] = dateFormatter.parse(m.group(1));
        dates[1] = dateFormatter.parse(m.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(dates[0]);
    System.out.println(dates[1]);
    return dates;
}
```

Little explanation:

In regex `.*(\\d{8})_(\\d{8}).*`:

- `.*` stands for *any sing repeated from zero to unlimited times*
- `(\\d{8})` stands for *exactly eight digits* (if they are in brackets they are considered **capturing groups**, we have 2 capturing groups in this regex, one for each date)
- `_` stands for `_` sign :)

If filename matches provided pattern both dates are extracted, parsed and returned as array. You should add some error handling etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a Java script (not Javascript) you can use regexp, something like the following:

```
String in = "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\repository\\zzz\\xxx_yyy\\new\\aaa_bbb_ppp_ccc_ddd_eee_ZZ_E_20160801_20160831_v1-0.csv";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\d{8})_v1-0");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to extract two dates which are present in each file path.
This could be done as follows:

```
String filename1 = "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\repository\\zzz\\xxx_yyy\\new\\aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_ZZ_E_20160801_20160831_v1-0.csv";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{8}+_[0-9]{8}+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(filename1);
String[] dateStrArr = m.find()?m.group(0).split("_"): null;
```

First date will be in 0 index and second date will be in 1 index position.

Same goes for second file name.
Hope this helps.

Also once extracted you can convert them to date object using SimpleDateFormat.